# CORS error when using SignalR Core in angular app

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

In CORS configuration, I am allowing OPTIONS method, but when I send a request, an error is thrown

> **OPTIONS http://x.x.x.x:port/function 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

my CORS Policy in **ConfigureServices** method in **Startup.cs** is as follows:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAny", x =>
  {
    x.AllowAnyOrigin()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     .WithMethods("POST", "OPTIONS");
  });
});
```

And it is used as follows:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAny");
```

**Hub Code:**

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message) {
   string outputMessage = SensorsControl.controlSensors(message.ToString()); 
   await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, outputMessage);
}
```

**SignalR Code in angular:**

```
this._hubConnection = new HubConnection('http://x.x.x.x:port/function'); 
this._hubConnection.start() 
                   .then(() => console.log('Connection started!')) 
                   .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection')); 
this._hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (user: string, outputMessage: string) => 
{ 
  const text = ${user}: ${outputMessage}; this.messages.push(text); 
});
```

Comment: Can you show your signalr code and your hub code ?

Comment: @TonyNgo anything else needed?

Comment: update in your question  not your comment

Comment: Done :) @TonyNgo

Comment: Try out with AllowAnyMethod() in CORS. `services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAny",
                x=>
                {
                    x
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });`

Comment: Didnt work :( It gives that no wildcard * allowed, and when I specify the verbs i.e. OPTIONS, GET, POST, the error changes to:  **has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: You can also try adding the headers elsewhere. I've often used web.config for this purpose: https://gist.github.com/Jalalhejazi/5653347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it guys :D The problem was that my angular app was hosted on localhost which was supposed to be my IPv4 IP, but it turned to be 127.0.0.1 which is not understood by the SignalR server. With no changes, I served angular using ng serve --host 0.0.0.0, and then connected using my IPv4 IP, worked as charm :D thanks for your help tho! Cheers!!